# Drawing on an Image HTML5 using

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I have an image and I want to be able to draw on it. I know how to draw on a canvas but my main problem is that currently, when I click on an image, it is not a canvas but an image. How can I get the canvas on top of the image so that I can draw on it?

I have this in my HTML:

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png" alt="Bart" class="img-responsive"/>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <div class="caption text-center">Bart Simpson</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is one alternative. Use a div, set this image as that's background and on that div use canvas. and do whatever you want.

Comment: Could you please provide a little code? An outline could work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is wait until the image is loaded. Use `drawImage` and draw it on your canvas. Then do whatever else you want to do with your canvas. Finally you can export the canvas again with `toDataURL` and set the source of an image

```js
var imageNode = document.getElementById('image');
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png";
image.onload = function() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
 canvas.width = image.width;
 canvas.height = image.height;
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

 // Do something like painting a green hat
 ctx.moveTo(35, 50);
 ctx.lineTo(85, 10);
 ctx.lineTo(135, 50);
 ctx.closePath();
 ctx.fillStyle = "#009900";
 ctx.fill();

 var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
 imageNode.src = dataURL;
}
```

```css
#image {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
 <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/aa/Bart_Simpson_200px.png" alt="Bart" id="image" class="img-responsive" />
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Should't we use `toDataURL()` on canvas and not context?